# Меню в виде адаптивной карусели

Tags: javascript, jquery

Вот так меню сверстал:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

при сжатии окна браузера один пункт за другим пропадают и появляются стрелки, а так же присутствует счетчик вот как задумывалось:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот состояние если немного пролистать:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А вот состояние если до конца про листать:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите способ или лучше пример где что-то похожее есть, буду рад любой помощи и информации.

Comment: от меня спасибо! легко и то что нужно..
ещё бы плавность прокрутки показали как прикруить =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это довольно просто можно реализовать с помощью [owl Carousel 2](https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/).

Я написал пример, вам остается только настроить внешний вид:

```js
$(".owl-carousel").owlCarousel({
  nav: true,
  onChanged: owlchange,
  onInitialized: owlchange,
  responsiveClass: true,
  //указываем количество меню на разных разрешениях
  responsive: {
    0: {
      items: 4,
      nav: true
    },
    600: {
      items: 6,
      nav: true
    },
    1000: {
      items: 8,
      nav: false //вырубаем навигацию, если не нужна

    }
  }
});

function owlchange(event) {
  //пересчитываем цифры и вписываем их в стрелки навигации
  $('.owl-prev').text(event.item.index)
  $('.owl-next').text(event.item.count - event.page.size - event.item.index)
}
```

```css
.owl-prev,
.owl-next {
  position: absolute;
  background: #ccc;
}
.owl-prev {
  left: 0;
}
.owl-next {
  right: 0;
}
.owl-prev:before {
  content: '<'
}
.owl-next:after {
  content: '>'
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.2.0/assets/owl.carousel.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.2.0/assets/owl.theme.green.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.2.0/owl.carousel.js"></script>
<div class="owl-carousel">
  <div>menu 1</div>
  <div>menu 2</div>
  <div>menu 3</div>
  <div>menu 4</div>
  <div>menu 5</div>
  <div>menu 6</div>
  <div>menu 7</div>
  <div>menu 8</div>
</div>
```